# ServiceStack HttpUtils + Proxy Server

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

I am using ServiceStack HttpUtils to connect to a third-party REST API.
How do I pass in Proxy Server and Proxy Port when making requests?

Thanks
rudrvij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils) is a wrapper over .NET's `HttpWebRequest` so you can use the same functionality to specify a [Proxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.proxy(v=vs.110).aspx), e.g:

```
url.GetJsonFromUrl(requestFilter: req.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://webproxy:80/"));
```

Or [set a Proxy globally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s8th0s1(v=vs.110).aspx) with:

```
WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("http://webproxy:80/");  
GlobalProxySelection.Select = proxyObject;
```

Or [configure it in Web.config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<configuration>  
  <system.net>  
    <defaultProxy>  
      <proxy  
        usesystemdefault="true"  
        proxyaddress="http://192.168.1.10:3128"  
        bypassonlocal="true"  
      />  
      <bypasslist  
        <add address="[a-z]+\.contoso\.com" />  
      </bypasslist>  
    </defaultProxy>  
  </system.net>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your response.